# Why are covariance and contravariance supported only for interfaces but not classes?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Is it some fundamental restriction (I really see none) or as Eric Lippert usually says: nobody just has proved it's worth implementing feature?

Comment: I'll just add that I miss that feature sometimes, in Scala concrete classes also can be co/contravariant...

Comment: Offtopic: Eric also wrote in one of his posts that in Scala you can say that expect some type which does this and that. Prototypical genereic restrictions. I REALLY miss this feature in C#. Quite often I need to require that a set of properties or methods is implemented.